# How to set price? in-app billing

Tags: android

I 'm trying to implement in-app billing in my app. And I use tutorial by Google, https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html.
 Here is a piece of code in that tutorial that I don't understand.

```
int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");

if (response == 0) {
   ArrayList<String> responseList
      = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

   for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
      JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
      String sku = object.getString("productId");

      String price = object.getString("price");   !!!

     if (sku.equals("premiumUpgrade")) mPremiumUpgradePrice = price;
      else if (sku.equals("gas")) mGasPrice = price;
   }
}
```

From where did they take a price??? I overlook the whole code on that page and didn't find any thing related to setting the price.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you set price in [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish).

Go to your app.  <kbd>Left Menu</kbd>  ->  <kbd>IN-APP PRODUCTS</kbd>  -> <kbd>Add new Product</kbd>

Then your app will fetch the price from Google Play servers.

Answer (score 0):

The price is actually being set in the Developer Console ...